# How to use tensorflow keras model to recognize number greater than 9 and float numbers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, handwriting-recognition

Is there anyway to use tensorflow keras with CNN model to train and recognize the number greater than 9 or decimal numbers? I means the value domain is between `0` to `20`, or deimal number from `0` to `10` like `0,1; 0,2;......;9,9`?

I've alread trainned model with MNIST dataset for digits number from 0 to 9, but i want to make sense with decimal and value domain greater than 9. Hope to see your idea about this...

For example number `10`

[image]

Or number `11`, `12`,....,`17`,...

[image] [image]

***UPDATE***
I tried with train model with some new number by given images above, but the predict still give false value. Here is some codes:

```
def trainDigitsModel(alwaysTrain=False, writeFile=True):
    modelExists = os.path.exists('traineddata/traineddata.model/saved_model.pb')
    
    if modelExists is False or alwaysTrain is True:
        # load data
        mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
        (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
        
        # Reshaping to format which CNN expects (batch, height, width, channels)
        X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2], 1).astype('float32')
        X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], X_test.shape[2], 1).astype('float32')
        
        # Load your own images to training and test data
        X_train, y_train = load_images_to_data('path/to/trainmore', X_train, y_train)
        X_test, y_test = load_images_to_data('path/to/trainmore', X_test, y_test)
        
        # normalize inputs from 0-255 to 0-1
        X_train/=255
        X_test/=255
        
        # one hot encode, value is 18 because i want to train more label from 10 - 17 -> totally has 18 from 0 - 17
        number_of_classes = 18

        y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, number_of_classes)
        y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, number_of_classes)
        
        # create model
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2], 1), activation='relu'))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
        model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
        model.add(Dropout(0.5))
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dropout(0.5))
        model.add(Dense(number_of_classes, activation='softmax'))
        
        # Compile model
        model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
        # Fit the model
        model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=5)
        
        if writeFile is True:
            model.save('traineddata/traineddata.model')
    else:
        # Load the model
        model = tf.keras.models.load_model('traineddata/traineddata.model')
    
    img = cv.imread('trainmore/12.png',0)
    # img = cv.GaussianBlur(img, (1,1), 0)
    img = cv.resize(img, (28,28))
    img = np.array(img)
    img = np.invert(img)
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()
    
    img = img.reshape(1,28,28,1)
    prediction = model.predict(img)
    result = np.argmax(prediction)
    print(prediction)
    print(result)
    
    return model
        
def load_images_to_data(image_label, image_directory, features_data, label_data):
    list_of_files = os.listdir(image_directory)
    for file in list_of_files:
        arr_file = file.split('.')
        image_label = arr_file[0]
        image_file_name = os.path.join(image_directory, file)
        if ".png" in image_file_name:
            img = cv.imread(image_file_name, 0)
            img = cv.resize(img, (28,28))
            im2arr = np.array(img)
            im2arr = np.invert(im2arr)
            # plt.imshow(im2arr)
            # plt.show()
            im2arr = im2arr.reshape(1,28,28,1)
            features_data = np.append(features_data, im2arr, axis=0)
            label_data = np.append(label_data, [image_label], axis=0)
    return features_data, label_data
```

Answer (score 0):

What I'll personally do is to train a number detector with a number recognizer on top, in the same idea of YOLO you know. First you train the detector to detect all the numbers in the image and in top of that you add your model trained on MNIST to classify each of the detected numbers.

Comment: I tried, and i also add some new number to orginal dataset of MNIST